# GZIP Wordpress login issue

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, gzip

I recently attempted to GZIP my wordpress site by adding the following code in my wordpress header.php file.

```
<?php if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], ‘gzip‘)) ob_start(“ob_gzhandler”); else ob_start(); ?>
```

The site no longer works because i keep getting "The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

The problem now is i cant go back into the wordpress admin panel AND REMOVE OR EDIT THIS CODE. My site is www.dentalonpark.au. I get the same error when trying to login.

The site only works when i remove the ".au" part, but every time i press a link it adds the ".au" bit and doesnt work.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Removing the code via FTP would be the most straightforward option.

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing all the details about the server configuration etc. FTP or direct command-line access to the server would be the two most likely candidates

Comment: Did you fix this?  It seems to work in Chrome (assuming you meant dentalonpark.com.au, not dentalonpark.au).  Perhaps you can fix it using a different browser, or stop your browser sending the gzip header until you get it fixed.